# Angular4 DataTable - Property '$key' does not exist

Tags: angular

I am using the Angular 4 datatable from here https://github.com/MIt9/angular-4-data-table and this is my code in my ProductsComponent.html:

```
<data-table [items]="items" [itemCount]="itemCount" 

(reload)="reloadItems($event)">

  <data-table-column [property]="'title'" [header]="'Title'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true"></data-table-column>

  <data-table-column [property]="'price'" [header]="'Price'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
      {{ item.price | currency:'USD'}}
    </ng-template>
  </data-table-column>

  <data-table-column [property]="$key">
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', item.$key]">Edit</a>
    </ng-template>
  </data-table-column>

</data-table>
```

The datatable renders all the data just fine, the browser doesnt show any errors and neither does the compilation during **ng serve**. However, when I run a **ng build --prod** I see the following error message and the build fails. Property '$key' does not exist on type 'ProductsComponent'. I am having a hard time debugging this as I don't see a bug when testing - any ideas whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $key in the property definition needed to be wrapped in quotes because I am not explicitly referencing a property from my component but a string property from the json object.

```
  <data-table-column [property]="'$key'">
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', item.$key]">Edit</a>
    </ng-template>
  </data-table-column>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is probably just a case of not setting 'public' on your variable '$key' in your component.ts file

this part of your code:
    `[property]="$key"`

as soon as you have a property/attribute enclosed in [] the value assigned to it will be evaluated e.g.

- `[property] = "'a string'"` evaluates to 'a string'
- `[property] = "$key"` looks for a variable named $key so it can bind the value of $key to property

You probably missing the quotes like so `[property]="'$key'"`

[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) has more info on this.

Comment: [$key] is defined by the datatable, I dont explicitly declare it anywhere.

Comment: Are u sure it's defined by the datatable, look at your first  2 data-table-column , maybe you should have surrounded $key with quotes like so ['$key']

Comment: by doing this [$key] you are trying to evaluate the value of $key which is why I initially thought you declared $key as a variable in your component.ts file, please provide a plunker next time so we can test your code